# Dealing with moved documents and sites in Sharepoint

Tags: iis, sharepoint, http, redirect

My organisation has recently restructured, and as a result, we have to move a bunch of team sites in our Sharepoint 2007 Intranet (MOSS).  This is going to result in changed URLs and broken links in plenty of documents.  Not a good situation.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to best handle this?

So far I have thought of the following options:

- Friendly custom 404 error pages for moved sites which give a link to the new site, and a search box with friendly text telling people to use it!
- Redirection to the new location

Given that only the root of each site will change (e.g. http://intranet/site/**old_dept**/teamsite becomes http://intranet/site/**new_dept**/teamsite) it should be possible to do smart redirection for the rest of the URL which actually points at the documents, pages etc.  I know this would be possible with Apache at least.  However, the combination of Sharepoint 2007 and IIS6 is making it hard to track down the best way of achieving a friendly solution that keeps the user happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your smart url redirection, check out the [RDA URL Redirection](http://rdacollaboration.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28073) utility.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I am looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things - you will want a temporary workaround:

- Use IIS to redirect requests for the old URL to the new - this will probably fail unless you also have an alternate access mapping for the old URL configured for the Web Application.
- Next, re-write the URL's "on-they-fly" with a URL Re-Writer as mentioned above - though there is an official one from Microsoft available at http://www.iis.net.

Then, long-term you are going to want to scan and update your content with the new URLs - SharePoint Desginer has some reports/scans under the "Site\Reports" menu.  But you may be better off with a custom utility.

Comment: When you talk about the long terms scan and update - are you suggesting there is some way of fixing links within Office documents stored in Sharepoint?

Comment: Unfortunately, the rewriter at www.iis.net seems to be only for IIS7 - we're still in IIS6 land as far as our Sharepoint infrastructure is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you will find the whole information about moving Sharepoint, content and database in these links. Hope it will help!

Regards,

- http://blogs.technet.com/corybu/archive/2007/06/21/sharepoint-site-migration-and-balancing-growth.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/priyo/archive/2006/09/15/755490.aspx
- http://sharepointsherpa.com/2008/04/18/sharepoint-2007-move-content-and-configuration-databases/

Comment: If you need more information, let me know, I'll give ya a hand.

Comment: Those articles discuss moving sites between content databases, which doesn't necessarily result in changed URLs.  We *want* to change the URLs so they reflect the site and organisational structure, yet make sure as few links as possible break (or handle broken links in a user friendly way).

Comment: To the change the URL, this is in the sharepoint high level settings. You should need to backup your old site and import it in the new site. If you have a lot of space on your dbase, you can keep it alive.

Basically, just create a new site name and import the old site on the new site... it's as simple as that.