# SharePoint 2007: Moving main site, to be a subsite - How can urls be redirected/changed?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, rewrite, url, url-routing

The setup:

- SharePoint 2007 (MOSS Enterprise) on WINSVR03/IIS6
- One site collection, with one access mapping (http://mainsite) currently

I'm moving the main SharePoint site, in our one site collection, to be a subsite in a new site collection. I'm using SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard to complete this task (http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/).

The Question

So the main site http://mainsite being moved has many subsites, etc. I want to be sure that urls like this:

http://mainsite/subsite/doclib/doc1.docx

map to and redirect to the new url:

http://newsite/mainsite/subsite/doclib/doc1.docx ?

And furthermore:

I'm aware of this - http://rdacollaboration.codeplex.com/releases/view/28073 , however is it IIS7 only? That'd wouldn't work for me.

Looking at this question - [Dealing with moved documents and sites in Sharepoint](https://serverfault.com/questions/107537/dealing-with-moved-documents-and-sites-in-sharepoint) is the only one I see that is similar.

Would an IIS redirect of http://mainsite to http://newsite/mainsite work only for the root url?

Comment: @program247365: can you elaborate on what you think makes your situation different than the one mentioned in the other SF question you linked? I'm having a hard time not marking this closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RDA Collaboration redirector is a SharePoint solution, so the underlying IIS version doesn't matter.

Comment: Neat. I missed that one.

Comment: Does the application also redirect for WEBDAV? So when someone opens up explorer, and then browses to //oldsiteurl/doclibrary, are they redirected to //newsiteurl/doclibrary ? If not, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good overview [here](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=48). That said, it sounds like you're going to need something like [URLRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/), [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/), [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/), or your own custom [httphandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457204.aspx).